# if / else if not working?

Tags: android, if-statement

I would like to build URL depending on Strings `choSection` and `choType` so I did some if else statement:

**1.** If both string are empty return basic url

```
   Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
            if(choSection.isEmpty()&& choType.isEmpty()) {
                return new NewsLoader(this,NEW``S_REQUEST_URL);       }
```

**2.** If only one is empty add only one parameter

```
else if (!choSection.isEmpty()&& choType.isEmpty())
     {uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("section", choSection);}
            return new NewsLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());
```

And it seems that the second condition where one string is empty is not working. What might be a reason?

Comment: "not working" is not a useful problem description. I recommend you find a tutorial on basic debugging.

Comment: Try using the debugger to examine the values. As was mentioned in the comment above, we need more information than "not working".

Comment: @glennsl @Vinnie thank you, i did some debugging and it showed that this first condition  if(choSection.isEmpty()&& choType.isEmpty()) {
                return new NewsLoader(this,NEW``S_REQUEST_URL);       } was redundant and causing problems. After removing it works well

Answer (score 1):

in the else part use this:  `else if (choSection.isEmpty() || choType.isEmpty())`  
`||` is the logical `or`  
Note that this will work only as the else part of your statement  
Alternatively if you want to check each of the 2 if they're empty do this:

```
if(choSection.isEmpty()&& choType.isEmpty()) {
    // your code
} else if (choSection.isEmpty()) {
    // your code
} else if (choType.isEmpty()) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: but if choType.isEmpty() I want to do sth else

Comment: exactly. the if statement will work if both are empty, if not the else part will work if one of them is empty

Comment: If none is empty nothing will be executed

Comment: @KateG do you want to do different things if choSection only is empty and choType only is empty ?

Comment: not quite,but I understand more now for else if statement

Comment: Why not quite? Did you want something else?

Comment: I did it like this:   if (!choSection.isEmpty()) {
            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("section", choSection);}

       if (!choType.isEmpty()) {
            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("type", choType);
       } else {
         return new NewsLoader(this, NEWS_REQUEST_URL);}

        return new NewsLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());
    }

Comment: @KateG Either what you do is wrong or this has nothing to do with the question as you phrased it.

Comment: I know. I wanted my app to load some news with only one of two parameters. I thought that if/else would help to do it but may be it's other issue

Comment: @KateG Take a look at my 3 part if/else statement in my answer. Is there something easier to understand than this?